# Create shared_ptr without copying instance

Tags: c++

I hope my question has not been posted in the past (I searched but I guess I'm not using right keywords, couldn't find anything).

I was wondering, is there a way to create a `shared_ptr` without copying the instance ? I mean, I saw that `make_shared` recreate what we pass as argument. So I tried to do it in `class A` with `shared_ptr(this)`, but I'm not sure it works as expected.

What does `shared_ptr(raw pointer)` exactly does ? Does it just stores the pointer or does it create a new instance using the copy constructor and storing its pointer ?

Thanks for your answer

Comment: See number 3 [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) for your second question.  I'm not sure what you are asking for in your first question.

Comment: You might want to read about [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).

Comment: `shared_ptr(raw_pointer)` will give ownership of an existing object pointed to by `raw_pointer` to the new `shared_ptr`. It will be deleted when that new `shared_ptr` and all copies of it are destroyed. No copies of the object refered to by `this` is made. `std::make_shared<T>(*this)` would make a new copy of the object which is owned by the new `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Mmh, okay, thank you for your answers ^^ question solved :3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would help if you [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  Given that you say you tried `std::shared_ptr(this)`, you may well be looking for `std::enable_shared_from_this`.

Comment: @NathanOliver question: will it call `double delete` issue when a function generate `shared_ptr` from a pointer? how to resolve it?

Answer (score 7):

```
A someInstance; 
auto sptr = std::make_shared<A>(someInstance)
```

Yes, in this case `sptr` will be new shared_pointer instance with newly created copy of `someInstance` (if `A` class has the public copy constructor defined - implicit or explicit).

What `std::make_shared(...)` does? It "tries" to match proper constructor basing on given parameters list. In this case, you pass `A const&' which will be matched to copy constructor.

Summarizing:

- `std::shared_ptr<T>(...)` creates `std::shared_ptr` from:

  - other shared_ptr,
  - `std::unique_ptr<T>`
  - pointer of T,
  - (empty shared_ptr)
- `std::make_shared<T>` creates `std::shared_ptr<T>` using `T` constructor

Comment: `std::make_shared<A>(std::move(someInstance));` might be useful to avoid copy. (even if `std::make_shared<A>(args);` would be more idiomatic).

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused as to how pointers behave...maybe? It is hard to decipher what you are asking.

I will take a stab with the following explanation though:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> mySharedPtr(new int(5));
```

creates one and only one instance of an int.

```
int * myPointer = new int(5);
std::shared_ptr<int> mySharedPtr(myPointer);
```

also creates one and only one instance of an int.

```
int * myPointer = new int(5);
std::shared_ptr<int> mySharedPtrA(myPointer);
std::shared_ptr<int> mySharedPtrB(mySharedPtrA);
```

also creates one and only one instance of an int.

```
std::shared_ptr<int> mySharedPtrA = std::make_shared<int>(5);
std::shared_ptr<int> mySharedPtrB = mySharedPtrA;
```

also creates one and only one instance of an int.

In all of those cases, the value of the int is 5, there is one instance, and the pointer to the int is being passed around.

The int is not being passed around, the pointer to the int is.
The int is not being copied, the pointer to the int is being copied.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But doesn't the ```A someInstance; std::make_shared<A>(someInstance)``` create a copy of someInstance ? That's what I tried to explain ^^'

Comment: The parameter to make_shared is not an instance, but a parameter for the construction of A. make_shared will construct an A, and that is the only instance there is, it returns a pointer to the instance, which does not copy the instance itself. shared_ptr<A> sharedPtr =  std::make_shared<A>(constructionParameterForA)

Comment: @ChristopherPisz it does create a copy tho

Comment: This doesn't work, `int * myPointer = new int(5); std::shared_ptr<int> mySharedPtr = myPointer;` results in `cannot convert from 'int *' to 'std::shared_ptr<int>'`